# How to solve Deep Link Enable in Android Using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, applinks, firebase-dynamic-links

[image: 1]

How to solve it problem and how to Enable App link Enable?.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html

Comment: i facing like this ...https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfRqZ.png

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug). Here:

> Android app lacks SHA256. AppLinks is not enabled for the app.
>
> To use Android App Links with your app, you must create a SHA256
>   certificate.
>
> Once you create the SHA256 certificate, add it to your app in the
>   Firebase console. See Add a SHA fingerprint.

Original page have inline links.